# How to use global object in VBA correctly?

Tags: c#, vba, ms-word, com, office-interop

I have a COM DLL written in c# to work with MS Word (using Interop) and use this COM into VB6 project.

In a module, I defined a global variable like this:

```
Public obj As Office.OfficeWord
```

In Form1:

```
Set obj = New OfficeWord
```

by creating the object, a word instance is created and I can see the instance in Task manager.
In Form2, I create a new document and close it (not Word.Application):

```
OfficeWord.CreateNewDoc
// doing some work   
OfficeWord.Close
```

When I close the Form2 and try to add a new document again (in Form1 or Form2) I get this error:
"Word has encountered a problem". However, the instance is alive and I can see it in the task manager.
I should mention that if I just work with Form1 everything is fine and I can add a new document and close it many times, In the end, close the instance too (obj.Quit) correctly, but when I want to work with the public object in Form2 I get the error above.

The C# DLL uses these lines of code to create and close the Word document and instance:

```
 public OfficeWord() 
 {
    wdapp = new Word.Application();
 }

public int CreateNewDoc()
{
   wddoc=wdapp.Documents.Add();
}

public int Close()
{
   object saveOption = Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges;
   object originalFormat = Word.WdOriginalFormat.wdOriginalDocumentFormat;
   object routeDocument = false;
   wddoc.Close(ref saveOption, ref originalFormat, ref routeDocument);
}

public int Quit()
{
    wdapp.Quit(false);   
}
```

using Form1, Form2, and public variable is mandatory.
Please guide me.
Thanks.

Comment: you could try not only to close it also set it to nothing, but why not let wddoc be local and give it as parameter to other functions?

Comment: Thanks @nbk. I set it to nothing, but the same result. I tried using wdapp.ActiveDocument instead of wddoc too but it does not make a difference.

Comment: There are two types of object 1) Early Binding 2) Late Binding.  Early Binding are objects that compiled while late binding the type is determined at runtime.  c# is managed where object types are are tested at runtime and exception occur when types are not recognized.  VB6 does not do the testing as well as c#.  Also c# add exceptions for when a program accesses memory outside the defined memory space (unsafe).  You can try to run the code as unsafe.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/unsafe-code

Comment: I think you mean VBA, not VB6.

Comment: @StayOnTarget : VBA is basic inside Microsoft Office Products.   VB6 is Microsoft Visual Basic 2006.

Comment: @jdweng yes. Since the COM DLL was written in C#, the VBx code shown here seems like it must be VBA within Word.

Comment: VB6 is Visual Basic 6; from 1998, not 2006. It’s 25+ year old technology.  More time has passed between VB6’s release and today, than between VB6 and the Altair kit computer

Answer (score 0):

It may seem a bit strange, but it works in "vb6" many times.
After you have used the corresponding object and no longer need it, set it to "Nothing".

In Form1:

```
Set obj = Nothing
Set obj = New OfficeWord
```

Comment: Thanks @BQF. You are right it is because of vb6.

Comment: VB6 compiler have "A Beautiful Mind". (@S.Parseh)